# Episode where Londo 'battles' an insect

Tags: episode-identification, babylon-5

This scene was, from what I remember, intended as comic relief. Ambassador Mollari complains to the personnel running the space station of a large insect in his quarters; upon being told by the staff they have bigger problems than pest control Londo stabs the insect with his Coutari (Centauri short sword)- only to realize the bug he skewered isn't the same one he complained about earlier and rants, "There are more of you- THERE ARE MORE OF YOU!"

Comment: "I swear, they are evolving before my very eyes. If you see something this big with eight legs, let me know. I have to kill it before it develops language skills."

Answer (score 13):

*Sic Transit Vir* is the name of the episode.

See the Lurker's Guide for additional analysis.
http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/056.html

Comment: its amazing that every time I go back and rewatch the series, I end up referencing that page. Almost 30 years old and still useful.